# Backup and restore of Hsqldb database through java code

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am new in Hsqldb database. I want to know how to take backup and restore of hsqldb database through java code.Please suggest answer.

Comment: I want this through java code like dump of mysql through code.it's urgent.

Comment: No one know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform the backup while database is being used, you use an SQL command like this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE TO ...
```

To restore the database, you use the main() method of the org.hsqldb.tar.DbBackup or org.hsqldb.tar.DbBackupMain (version 2.3.2 or later) depending on the version of HSQLDB.

The commands are explained here:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_backup